# VSCode Theme of React Documentation

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

React has [this awesome documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) with a lot of code samples. It [says](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects) the docs are using [Oceanic Next](https://labs.voronianski.com/oceanic-next-color-scheme/) color scheme for its code samples which clearly doesn't. (e.g. the color of `this` keyword or `class methods`)

Does anyone know which color theme is actually being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made one. I took a few liberties, but its super similar => [Oceanic Next Custom](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shawdaddy.oceanic-next-custom-dark)

Comment: Please update your theme so I can try it. I'm currently receiving this error trying to install: `Unable to install because, the extension 'shawdaddy.oceanic-next-custom-dark' compatible with current version '1.19.1' of VS Code is not found.`

Comment: I updated it. It should now work with a minimum vscode version of 1.18.0.

Comment: JSX tag colors are not fixed yet, but I appreciate your work.

Comment: No sir, I see it as yellow.

Comment: Oh thats right, default html tags are red and user defined component tags show up as yellow. I like this behavior, but I can make you a version with all jsx tags red.

Comment: That's fine thank you. So it appears that React Documentation is using a custom defined theme which is not publicly released.

Comment: Yeah I looked around for it and couldn't find anything, that's why I ended up making my own version.  
 Ive made you a version with all jsx tags red, [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shawdaddy.oceanic-next-maleki-custom)

Comment: Thank you sir. This is not actually the answer but we made a conclusion so I'll mark it for others to see your work.

Comment: @bitwitch How easy is it to make the comment italic and background light?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca pretty easy. just need to change the background color everywhere and add a setting for comments. it's easy enough in vscode. you could either just manually override the background color and add a setting for italic comments in your user settings, or you could generate a color theme (open the command pallette cmd+shift+p, select Generate Color Theme From Current Settings) and then change the settings in the generated theme and save it where your themes are stored (probably ~/.vscode/extensions).

Answer (score 2):

Someone asked this question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/9jtxv7/anyone_know_what_theme_is_being_used_in_the_docs/) and got a response from a member of the React core team:

> I think Joe (the designer that came up with the overall current design) picked these theme colors from his Photoshop palette. It's a custom theme, but you can grab the colors from GitHub. You can find the color scheme here by the way: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/master/src/prism-styles.js#L11

The color scheme linked to is:

```
const prismColors = {
  char: '#D8DEE9',
  comment: '#B2B2B2',
  keyword: '#c5a5c5',
  lineHighlight: '#353b45', // colors.dark + extra lightness
  primitive: '#5a9bcf',
  string: '#8dc891',
  variable: '#d7deea',
  boolean: '#ff8b50',
  punctuation: '#88C6BE',
  tag: '#fc929e',
  function: '#79b6f2',
  className: '#FAC863',
  method: '#6699CC',
  operator: '#fc929e',
};
```

However, I'm not sure how to customize or build a theme to incorporate these colors.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find one that was actually faithful to the website, so I made one (it's close enough for me, but feel free to open issues on the [repo](https://github.com/oessaid/react-theme-faithful) if something bothers you).

You can download it directly from VS Code's marketplace, specifically [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MoonHealth.react-theme-faithful).

**Some background**

I used the [link](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/master/src/prism-styles.js#L11) provided by React's core theme in that Reddit thread, but also the general colours used in the website's [theme](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/master/src/theme.js). Finally, I went extensively through the website itself and tried to stick to it as much as possible.

I use it daily on a React/React Native/Vue.js/Python+Django codebase and it looks good and readable everywhere (in my humble opinion).

Anyway, it's not much, but it's honest work.

**What does it look like?**

[image: Screnshot]

Comment: This one is great, looks very similar.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Oceanic Next Color Theme by Dmitri Voronianski
2. In your VS Code, go to file and then preferences and click on color scheme
3. As a result of your installation, you would see two new themes there as you scroll down: Oceanic Next and Oceanic Next (dimmed bg)
4. **Oceanic Next (dimmed bg)** is the theme you are looking for

Comment: I'm afraid it's not. Color of JSX tags, `this` keyword and some other stuff doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this
[Base16 Ocean Kit](https://github.com/viatsko/awesome-vscode#base16-ocean-kit) .

Comment: I think not. e.g. JSX tag colors are different.

Answer (score 0):

I "converted" from Atom to Visual Studio Code last weekend - this is the way I did it - following the tip at the bottom of this page:
https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

My "how-to":

1. Install the extension "Sublime Babel" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joshpeng.sublime-babel-vscode
2. Install one of the "Oceanic Next" themes - the ones I tried are all (!) working, i.e. you have a choice
3. "Reload" via the button shown

And then nothing happened ... ;) as I forgot this:

4. Ctrl-K Ctrl-T (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)

And then - play around.

When you are new to an editor you overlook sometimes the obvious - you have to tell Visual Code which enabled theme to use. Once you know it - pretty straight forward (;) as always).

I chose finally this one:
https://github.com/voronianski/oceanic-next-color-scheme

I simply wanted the background as dark as possible and it contains a "dimmed" version ;) but that's a matter of taste and you are where you want to be.